# Slick.js is breaking Foundation clearing lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation, slick.js

I'm having trouble getting Slick.js and the Foundation clearing lightbox to play nicely together. The way I have my site set up is that there are three 'pages', but each page is a Slick.js slide, so the site is really only one actual webpage.

In my photography 'slide', I have a basic lightbox setup with Foundation. However, I cannot get the lightbox to open properly when Slick.js is enabled. It works just fine when Slick.js is disabled.

You can see a live example here: [www.kcfeatures.com/services.html](http://www.kcfeatures.com/services.html)

Here's a working live example (slick.js is disabled): [www.kcfeatures.com/services1.html](http://www.kcfeatures.com/services.html)

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get it to work. My guess is that it has to do with the slick-track? Since the slick-track div is so wide it might be messing with how the lightbox is displayed. Lightbox also normally starts at the very top of the viewport, but with slick.js enabled it starts underneath the topbar, where the slider starts.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Even I tried to implement something similar but slick didn't allow my clearing lightbox to work.

Suggestions/Workarounds

1. Try Foundation 5 Reveal modal. 
   Have separate divisions for every thumbnail image that would contain the large version of the image. Tweak your code to trigger the reveal modal for every  thumbnail displaying the larger version. However this will not allow you to move through other images as clearing lightbox would do. (You can implement a slick slider inside your reveal modal div to make that happen.)
2. How about using Foundation Tabs ?
   I saw your website, except for the slide in effect of photography, videography and web design divs there is no need specific need for slick usage. I believe you can use Foundation Tabs and implement the same (Using clearing lightbox will be super easy now). If you want animation for your tabs you can refer Jquery Slide animations and implement the same for your tabs. You can also refer Foundation Tabs animation using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337948/fade-in-tabs-in-zurb-foundation/21129153#21129153).

Comment: Well I'm glad it's not just me! I like your suggestion of using Foundation Tabs; I'll work on an implementation of that. The animation would be nice but is definitely not necessary!